# Site search analysis using BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm new to BigQuery export schema and I'm trying to analyse the site search pattern in an e-commerce website.

I would like to get the steps made per session once someone uses the search bar in the site. I want to retrieve the keywords used and the urls (a.k.a = searchPath, previousSearchPath and nextSearchPath).

Whit this, I want to check :

- When (after n hits/interactions) a user consider to search in our website
- The last url he/she visited before searching
- The result page he visit after the search
- Following actions

So far, I got this query. However, the prev_page_path/step/nextStep don't match something logic. I obtain somthing like:

- product-list-page/
- product-list-page/2
- product-list-page/3

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING)) AS sessionId,
  IF(cd.index=7,cd.value,NULL) AS customDimension7,
  IF(cd.index=179,cd.value,NULL) AS customDimension179,
  h.contentGroup.contentGroup2 AS CG,
  h.hitNumber AS hitNumber,
  h.page.searchKeyword AS keyword,
  LAG(h.page.pagePath, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING)) ORDER BY h.hitNumber) AS prev_page_path,
  h.page.pagePath AS step,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING)) ORDER BY hitNumber ASC) AS rowNumber,
  LEAD(h.page.pagePath, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING)) ORDER BY hitNumber ASC) AS nextStep
FROM
  `xxx-xx-xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS h,
  UNNEST(h.customDimensions) AS cd
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
  AND cd.index = 12
  AND h.page.searchKeyword IS NOT NULL
  AND cd.value >= '1'
LIMIT
  100
```

Comment: Can you show which transformations you want to do in your data? I mean, what is the initial data and which outputs do you expect.

Comment: Hi, the transformation needed is that, using the sessionId behaviour through the web, I would like to obtain the page.Path during each of them ONLY if they use the site search bar.
Let's say that someone land in the e-commerce homepage and, from there, I click on "sales" after that, I click on "Suits" but, since I was looking for "fancy shirts" and (yet) didn't obtain any result I like. I use the search bar.
Therefore, with the query above, I want to obtain:
- page.Path where I first used the search site bar
- page.Path of the results
- page.Path of the following steps
- Keywords used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to add an event for site search tracking. Therefore, I now have the sessions that triggers that event, plus the results using hit.page.searchKeywords and everything else that I need to calculate the metrics needed.

```
WITH event AS (
  SELECT
      CONCAT(fullVisitorId, visitStartTime) as sessionId,
      CASE WHEN hit.eventInfo.eventAction= 'sitesearch' THEN hit.page.pagePath ELSE NULL END AS pagepath_search,
    FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*` AS ga,  UNNEST(hits) AS hit
    WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = 'date'
                ),
keyword AS (
   SELECT 
    CONCAT(fullVisitorId, visitStartTime) as sessionId,
    hit.page.searchKeyword as keyword,
    hit.page.pagePath AS pagepath_result,
  FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*` AS ga,  UNNEST(hits) AS hit
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = 'date'
            )

SELECT 
  keyword.keyword, 
  evento.pagepath_search, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT keywords.sessionId) AS total_sessions
FROM
  event INNER JOIN keyword ON event.sessionId = keyword.sessionId
```

I'm always learning about this so, if you know something that could be better, hit me up!